# Get demographic information by condition using table() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, subset

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame (ID  = c(1:20),
                  Ethnicity = c(rep(c("White", "Asian", "Black", "Hispanic", "Other"), times=20/5)),
                  Age = c(1:20),
                  Set = rep(c(1,2,3,4), times=20/4)
)
```

I want to know the `ethnicity` and `age` breakdown by `Set`. I usually use `table(df$ethnicity)`, but how do I do this by `Set`?

The desired output for ethnicity is a table with the percentage of each `ethnicity` by `Set`. For example, in this case, all sets will have 20% White, 20% Asian, 20% Black, 20% Hispanic, 20% Other. As for age, it will output the mean age of each set in a table.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean like `with(df, table(Age, Set))` or `table(df$Age, df$Set)`? Or what exactly is the desired output for this sample input?

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the comment, just edited the question for greater clarity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prop.table`:

```r
prop.table(table(df$Ethnicity, df$Set), 2)

             1   2   3   4
  Asian    0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
  Black    0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
  Hispanic 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
  Other    0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
  White    0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
```

For numeric x categorical, you can use `by`:

```r
by(df$Age, df$Ethnicity, mean)

df$Ethnicity: Asian
[1] 9.5
------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Ethnicity: Black
[1] 10.5
------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Ethnicity: Hispanic
[1] 11.5
------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Ethnicity: Other
[1] 12.5
------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Ethnicity: White
[1] 8.5
```